# how to move only files to subdirectory in linux

Tags: linux

I would like to create a sub directory and move only files from the directory dir to the new created sub directory. I tried this:

```
$ mkdir  dir/subdir ----> subdir is created
$ mv -if dir/* dir/subdir -----> all files and directories in dir will be moved into dir/subdir
```

How to move only files to subdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find(1)`.

```
$ mkdir dir/subdir
$ find dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} dir/subdir \;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ find dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} dir/subdir \;
```

Comment: I get the error: find: paths must precede expression: 1

Comment: @Ronald The option was `-maxdepth` not `-depth`.  This was correctly pointed out in the other answer, so you should accept that one.